# Multiple Jquery dialogs on page using same classes

Tags: jquery, dialog, jquery-selectors

I have multiple places on my page where I want to open a jquery dialog boxes when a link is clicked. I am using class selectors so in theory I should be able to open each of them. My problem is that with the code I have it will only open the first dialog I click. Why is this???

```
    //modal help div
    $('.dialogbox').dialog({
                   modal:true,
                   autoOpen: false
                   });
    $(".modalhelp").click(function() {
$('.dialogbox').dialog('open')
```

});

The html:

```
<a class="modalhelp" href="javascript:void[0]"><img src="images/information.png" /></a>
<div class="dialogbox" style="display:none" title="Information">Hello</div>

<a class="modalhelp" href="javascript:void[0]"><img src="images/information.png" /></a>
<div class="dialogbox" style="display:none" title="Information">NO HELLO</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

In your [`.click()`](http://api.jquery.com/click/) handler you need to reference the one you want relatively, like this:

```
$(".modalhelp").click(function() {
  $(this).next('.dialogbox').dialog('open');
});
```

Instead of opening all `.dialogbox` elements, we're only calling `.dialog('open')` on the *very next* sibling `<div class="dialogbox">` by using [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/).  If there may be elements in-between the clicked anchor and the `.dialogbox` then then this would change a bit, for example [`.nextAll('.dialogbox:first')`](http://api.jquery.com/nextAll/).